# Rider IDE - How to pin an opening file tab to pull it right

Tags: ide, rider

In Rider IDE - How can I pin an opening file tab to pull it right like Visual studio behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is under development by Jetbrains.

Find it out from jetbrains support channel [Pin Tabs, like in Visual Studio](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000757584-Pin-Tabs-like-in-Visual-Studio)

Following this one for the update

[RIDER-11901 Add option for pinned tabs to be shown in separate row](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-11901)

Comment: @KhoaVan   ohh, is this support for the lastest?

Comment: @johnson not so far, just follow up https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FRIDER-11901

Comment: Click `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`A` and start typing `Show Pinned tabs in a separate row`. It looks like [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-941550?sign=MTYzMTkyMzIwMDAwMHwxMS0xfDc0LTk0MTU1MHxUeUZJNUo2ck1VSjVHeWFDams2bURrQXZadmtS%0D%0AeVpDME9lcjRiSDdqTFpzDQo%0D%0A&updated=1603218945565)